How to fix sb.AnchorUtils.loadEnv() wrong keyfile path?
I am using this switchboard function in my typescript code:
const { keypair, connection, program } = await sb.AnchorUtils.loadEnv();

When I run this code it thinks the keyfile path is ./target/deploy/sb_randomness-keypair.json while the correct path is actually ./sb-randomness/target/deploy/sb_randomness-keypair.json
Full error:
/Users/jim/trash/cde-t/sb-on-demand-examples/sb-randomness-on-demand/node_modules/.pnpm/ts-node@10.9.2_@types+node@22.7.2_typescript@5.6.2/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:859
    return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes, diagnostics);
           ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
index.ts:28:57 - error TS2339: Property 'loadEnv' does not exist on type 'typeof import("/Users/jim/trash/cde-t/sb-on-demand-examples/sb-randomness-on-demand/node_modules/.pnpm/@coral-xyz+anchor@0.30.1/node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/dist/cjs/index")'.

28   const { keypair, connection, program } = await anchor.loadEnv();
                                                           ~~~~~~~
index.ts:149:54 - error TS7006: Parameter 'line' implicitly has an 'any' type.

149   let resultLog = answer?.meta?.logMessages?.filter((line) =>
                                                         ~~~~

    at createTSError (/Users/jim/trash/cde-t/sb-on-demand-examples/sb-randomness-on-demand/node_modules/.pnpm/ts-node@10.9.2_@types+node@22.7.2_typescript@5.6.2/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:859:12)
    at reportTSError (/Users/jim/trash/cde-t/sb-on-demand-examples/sb-randomness-on-demand/node_modules/.pnpm/ts-node@10.9.2_@types+node@22.7.2_typescript@5.6.2/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:863:19)
    at getOutput (/Users/jim/trash/cde-t/sb-on-demand-examples/sb-randomness-on-demand/node_modules/.pnpm/ts-node@10.9.2_@types+node@22.7.2_typescript@5.6.2/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1077:36)
HELLOOOO
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './target/deploy/sb_randomness-keypair.json'
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:448:20)
    at Function.<anonymous> (/Users/jim/trash/cde-t/sb-on-demand-examples/sb-randomness-on-demand/node_modules/.pnpm/@switchboard-xyz+on-demand@1.2.41_fastestsmallesttextencoderdecoder@1.0.22/node_modules/@switchboard-xyz/on-demand/src/anchor-utils/AnchorUtils.ts:56:32)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/jim/trash/cde-t/sb-on-demand-examples/sb-randomness-on-demand/node_modules/.pnpm/@switchboard-xyz+on-demand@1.2.41_fastestsmallesttextencoderdecoder@1.0.22/node_modules/@switchboard-xyz/on-demand/dist/cjs/anchor-utils/AnchorUtils.js:31:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (/Users/jim/trash/cde-t/sb-on-demand-examples/sb-randomness-on-demand/node_modules/.pnpm/@switchboard-xyz+on-demand@1.2.41_fastestsmallesttextencoderdecoder@1.0.22/node_modules/@switchboard-xyz/on-demand/dist/cjs/anchor-utils/AnchorUtils.js:27:12)
    at Function.initKeypairFromFile (/Users/jim/trash/cde-t/sb-on-demand-examples/sb-randomness-on-demand/node_modules/.pnpm/@switchboard-xyz+on-demand@1.2.41_fastestsmallesttextencoderdecoder@1.0.22/node_modules/@switchboard-xyz/on-demand/dist/cjs/anchor-utils/AnchorUtils.js:74:16)
    at Function.<anonymous> (/Users/jim/trash/cde-t/sb-on-demand-examples/sb-randomness-on-demand/node_modules/.pnpm/@switchboard-xyz+on-demand@1.2.41_fastestsmallesttextencoderdecoder@1.0.22/node_modules/@switchboard-xyz/on-demand/src/anchor-utils/AnchorUtils.ts:44:39)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/jim/trash/cde-t/sb-on-demand-examples/sb-randomness-on-demand/node_modules/.pnpm/@switchboard-xyz+on-demand@1.2.41_fastestsmallesttextencoderdecoder@1.0.22/node_modules/@switchboard-xyz/on-demand/dist/cjs/anchor-utils/AnchorUtils.js:31:71 {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: './target/deploy/sb_randomness-keypair.json'

How can I make it use the correct keyfile path?

sb.AnchorUtils.initKeypairFromFile('./sb-randomness/target/deploy/sb_randomness-keypair.json');

Please make sure your project structure.
https://github.com/switchboard-xyz/sb-on-demand-examples/tree/main/sb-randomness-on-demand

If your project is not working, then please refer this GitHub project.
It is working well in my side.

That's the project I am trying to run, but it is not working for me. You had to edit this line in order to get it running, right?

If you run this project, then you don't need to edit anything.

Just clone, and follow readme, that's fine

This is definitely NOT the correct solution... sb.AnchorUtils.initKeypairFromFile cannot be using in place of sb.AnchorUtils.loadEnv because they both return completely different things...

As I said, it is working well, Just clone again and follow readme file.
